# .htaccess: how to make a digit parameter optional?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

In my example, this URL works with these parameters:

```
www.website.com/search/dogs-10-cats-5
```

what I want is to have one of the parameters (a digit or empty) to be optional like:

```
www.website.com/search/dogs--cats-3
```

Is this possible?  Here is my current rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^search/dogs-?([0-9]+)-cats-?([0-9]+)/? index.php?SearchResults&Dogs=$1&Cats=$2 [L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dogs-?([0-9]*)-cats-?([0-9]+)
```

instead of

```
dogs-?([0-9]+)-cats-?([0-9]+)
```

`+` means "one or more", `*` means "zero or more"

I would also recommend to omit the `?`s, because this makes every second dash optional (may be intended, but I guess not)

```
dogs10-cats5
```

Comment: Interesting, so with your solution, if I have:

dogs-c-cats-10 or dogs-c9-cats-10 

it only passes the digit on and empty string for anything else.  I believe this will work!